# Custom API how to return int field

Tags: query, mysql

I have a custom table in db with a column `recommendation` of type `int(11)`.
Then as one of my custom route handlers I have

```
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "SELECT recommendation FROM `restaurants`;
  // todo convert "88" -> 88
  $list1 = $wpdb->get_results($query);
  
  return array('open' => $list1);
```

The data the front end receives is `"88"` whereas this should be an int.

In some of my code I have a function that maps each `$obj` in the list with

```
$obj->recommendation = (int) $obj->recommendation;
```

But it feels weird that I need to post process in php rather than get the data correctly from the db itself.

What is the 'best' way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What type of column is the data stored in, in the database?

Comment: phpmyadmin reports it as `int(11)`